# Odd compiler error when using Obj-C objects in a switch statement

Tags: objective-c, c, syntax, compiler-errors, switch-statement

I get a compiler error when using an Objective-C object within a switch statement:

```
switch (myConstant)
{
    case 0:
        UIViewController *myController = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
        break;
    case 1:
        // stuff
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

The error states:

> Expected expression before 'UIViewController'
>   'myViewController' undeclared (first use in this function)

I understand that the second error is a direct result of the first error, but what I don't understand is why I get the 'expected expression' error in the first place...

If I put a `;` at the end of the `case 0:` line, then it will compile, but I shouldn't have to do this, no?

This will also fail to compile, with the same error:

```
switch (0)
{
    case 0:
        int a = 0;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

However, if I declare the `int a;` outside of the switch block, then `a = 0;` compiles fine.

I thought I understood switch statements - clearly I don't. Could someone please explain?

Comment: You should buy a book about the C language. A case inside a switch must be followed by a statement. You followed it by a declaration, which is not a statement. A ";" on its own is an empty statement. It is preferable to always use a compound statement { ... } except for the simplest cases.

Comment: @gnasher729 thanks for letting me know this 4 years later ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add {} within the case if you declare a new variable. The case part of a switch statement is not a correct scope to declare variables in C.

```
 case 0:
     {
        int a = 0;
        break;
    }
...
```

Comment: Oh of course... Looks like I had a major brain fart... Thanks!

Comment: I planned on accepting - however there seems to be a 10 minute period before being allowed to accept answers on new questions. I got distracted - sorry.